# How to override default mode in HAProxy Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, haproxy, kubernetes-networking, haproxy-ingress

I am using the HAProxy ingress controller in my EKS Kubernetes setup.

Recently I tried to set up a Redis instance on my k8s.

When I tried to connect and run any command from outside the cluster, I got the following error:

```
❱❱❱ redis-cli -h redis-ingress.local  -p 80 info 
Error: Protocol error, got "H" as reply type byte
```

On further  debugging, I found the issue, that HAProxy needs to be running in `TCP mode`, and it is failing as the default mode is set to `HTTP`.

To solve this, I added the following annotation to my Redis-service, which should have solved the problem, but it didn't. I still keep getting the same error.

```
annotations:
    haproxy.org/backend-config-snippet: |
      mode tcp
```

I logged into one of the HAProxy containers to check the config, being used, and found the following block:

```
backend redis-service-redis 
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option forwardfor
  ###_config-snippet_### BEGIN
  mode tcp
  ###_config-snippet_### END
  server SRV_1 172.19.51.245:6379 check weight 128
  server SRV_2 127.0.0.1:6379 disabled check weight 128
```

As I can see, the config from the annotation is being applied, but it is not overwriting the `mode`.

I have few queries

- How to overwrite the `HTTP` or whatever the global mode is set for a particular backend/Service?
- If both the `mode` are specified in the `backend`(as in the above case), which one takes the preference?